# Is it possible to have a 32 bit ODBC connection on Windows 10 without a tnsnames.ora file?

Tags: vba, oracle, odbc, instantclient

I have a VBA (Excel) macro that connects to and queries an Oracle database.  Running under Windows 7, the following connection string works:

```
Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(PORT=xxx))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=name))); Uid=username;Pwd=password;
```

I and the rest of the users of this Excel template are being transitioned to Windows 10 (64 bit), with 32 bit Office 365.  What I like about this connection string is that it doesn't require a separate tnsnames.ora file, a feature I'd like to keep.  I also know that the Microsoft drivers are being deprecated (and it doesn't work out of the box anyway), so the time to change it is now.

I have the following installed:

- Oracle Instant Client 12.2 (32 bit)
- Oracle ODBC Drivers for Instant Client 12.2 (32 bit)
- Visual Studio 2019 (32 bit)(assuming the Oracle drivers are forward-compatible)

I have verified that:

- the first value in PATH is set to the directory where Instant Client 12.2 is installed
- ORACLE_HOME is set to the same directory
- there is only one ORACLE_HOME variable
- The driver (Oracle in instantclient_12_2) is visible in the 32 bit ODBC admin tool

I've tried various tweaks of the following connection string, with no luck

```
Driver={Oracle in instantclient_12_2}; Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(PORT=xxx))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=name))); Uid=username;Pwd=password
```

I've tried using "Data Source" in place of "Server", "SERVICE_NAME" in place of "SID", and both at the same time.  I've also tried the string in Excel 365's internal ODBC connection.  The error I keep receiving is:

> ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

I'm starting to get the suspicion that a tnsname.ora file is necessary under Windows 10. Is it possible to create a Windows 10 32 bit OBDC connection without using a tnsnames.ora file or any other actions aside from installing the Oracle drivers on a user's machine?

Edit: I created a remotely accessible tnsnames file.  When the connection string uses that file and the TNS_ADMIN environment variable is set, it connects.  If I use the exact text from the tnsnames file in VBA itself, it does not recognize it (TNS Adapter Error).  I'm going to assume that my suspicion about the Oracle drivers requiring a tnsnames.ora file is true, at least for VBA.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your specific question but having a tnsnames file does provide you a nice layer of abstraction between your individual workbooks and whatever database(s) you use - when you upgrade/migrate the DB you only need to fix one file (and that can be in a shared location - does not need to be on your local PC)

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. I'm assuming that I'd set the environment variable for the tnsnames file to a network location vs a local one?

Comment: Yes that's a pretty common scenario and works well - if you need to test a new database you can switch your tnsnames to a local one to verify it's OK before updating the "master" copy.

Comment: That's what I'll be doing then. Thanks!

Comment: The `tnsnames.ora` file is used to provide an alias for your data source. Since you put the full `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(PORT=xxx))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=name)))` in your connection string you bypass the tnsnames.ora file, i.e. you are not using tnsnames.ora anyway.

Comment: I'm aware of that.  The issue is that I haven't found a working connection string for the Win10 32-bit Oracle drivers that connects.

Comment: I don't use Windows, and have used ODBC a little on Linux.  My .odbc.ini file on Linux has `ServerName = localhost/orclpdb1` which is the Easy Connect syntax of dbservername/servicename.  Note you can't use SIDs but need a service name.   My config also has `Driver =  /home/oracle/app/oracle/product/18.0.0/dbhome_1/lib/libsqora.so.18.1`. Another comment is that with Instant Client you don't need to set ORACLE_HOME.

Comment: Was the change from SERVICE_NAME in your working example to SID in your non working example deliberate?  If SERVICE_NAME worked in one example, then this is the way to go.

Comment: Yes. I tried both SERVICE_NAME and SID in the connection string, and received the same error each time.

Comment: Without setting ORACLE_HOME, Windows would not even recognize that the driver was installed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ODBC drivers, one (deprecated) from Microsoft and the other one from Oracle. The connection strings are slightly different.

- Oracle Driver (see https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-in-orahome92/ or [Using the Oracle ODBC Driver](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm#ADFNS1183)):

  `Driver={Oracle in instantclient_12_2};Uid=username;Pwd=secret;DBQ=(DESCRIPTION=...)`
- Microsoft Driver (see https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-oracle/ or [Connection String Format and Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/connection-string-format-and-attributes?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017)):

  `Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Uid=username;Pwd=secret;Server=(DESCRIPTION=...)`

The "Oracle ODBC Drivers for Instant Client" includes the Instant Client, so there is not need to install it separately. You only get the risk of mismatches and messed up directories.

Comment: Step one of the Instant Client ODBC installation for Windows is "Install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package, as described above." When I unzip the file manually, all it contains are the ODBC-related files, not the entire Instant Client package.

Comment: I tried formatting the connection string exactly as you have it above, with the Uid and Pwd before the "DBQ=" portion.  I received a different error: "ORA-12154 TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified".  I also tried it in the original order I had it in above, and received the same error.

Comment: Maybe you have to surround the data source by curling brackets, `{}` (like the Driver name)

Comment: Can you connect with sqlplus (or tnsnping) with the same data source string?

Comment: `DBQ=` for the Oracle driver was the part I was missing. Works find for me now with `isql` using the #21 driver without having to create tnsnames.ora. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and came to the conclusion that the Oracle ODBC Driver just doesn't support the Connect Descriptor syntax.  It will only take a TNS Name.

This Oracle web page gives information on the parameters the Oracle ODBC Driver will accept in the connection string:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_odbc.htm?ref=binfind.com/web

It states the Dbq parameter takes a TNS Service Name.  That's it. No mention is made anywhere on the page of a Connect Descriptor.  Also, the "Server" and "CONNECTSTRING" parameters that *did* take a Connect Descriptor in the connection string for the Microsoft ODBC for Oracle driver aren't mentioned anywhere on the page.

It's hard to "prove a negative." But I've come to the sorry conclusion that the Oracle ODBC Driver doesn't support Oracle's own Connect Descriptor syntax based on:

- Oracle's documentation only shows support for the TNS Service Name; and
- ConnectionStrings.com only shows examples using the TNS Service Name, not the Connect Descriptor; and
- Months of my own experimenting, using different drivers and different
  combinations of keywords and the values in the connection string